# How to Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: powershell, tensorflow

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_object_detection), and there is a section that says the Object Detection API needs to be installed with the following commands:

```
sudo apt install -y protobuf-compiler
cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
```

When I do this sudo is not recognized, and upon Googling it says that this is a Linux only command so I am kinda confused as to what to do. When I run in admin mode and remove sudo, there is still many other errors. The other errors are the following:
sudo : The term 'sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
At line:1 char:1
+ sudo apt install -y protobuf-compiler
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sudo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Quentin\models\research\' because it does not exist.
At line:2 char:1
+ cd models/research/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Quentin\models\research\:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

protoc : The term 'protoc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:1
+ protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (protoc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

cp : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Quentin\object_detection\packages\tf2\setup.py' because it does not exist.
At line:4 char:1
+ cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Quenti...es\tf2\setup.py:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

I have tried putting this is in Powershell, Dev Terminal and NuGet Package manager and none have worked so far.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The instructions apply to Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Do you know how/where I would find Windows instructions? It is confusing because the other commands in this tutorial series have worked for me on Windows and the tutorials do not indicate that Linux is required.

Comment: A quick web search led me to [this](https://medium.com/@marklabinski/installing-tensorflow-object-detection-api-on-windows-10-7a4eb83e1e7b)

Comment: Thank you so much, idk how I missed this! I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @QuentinHerzig, For windows you can use `pip install protobuf-compiler` to download the package. Sudo is for the linux so you cannot use it on the windows machine.Thank You!